# Set up Slurm accounting (sacct) with AWS ParallelCluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, slurm

I'm trying to set up a Slurm computing cluster on AWS using AWS ParallelCluster to use for some of our batch processing needs.  However, I've found that Slurm's job accounting facilities are not set up by default.  For example, running the command `sacct` simply responds with `Slurm accounting storage is disabled`.  What would be the appropriate approach to enable Slurm accounting, either before the cluster is built or after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a later date to when this question was asked, a detailed set of instructions for enabling Slurm accounting with AWS ParallelCluster was posted at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/enabling-job-accounting-for-hpc-with-aws-parallelcluster-and-amazon-rds/.